# How to filter array object based on array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have the original data array. How to filter array object based on the array object

```
const products = [
  {
    options: [
       { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '10'},
       { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'yellow'},
    ],
  },
  {
    options: [
       { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '20'},
       { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'yellow'},
    ],
  },
  {
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '10'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'pink'},
    ],
  },
  { 
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '20'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'pink'}
    ],
  },
  {
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '39'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'pink'},
    ],
   },
];
```

And a filter array object:

```
const conditions = [
  [
    { name: 'Size',value: '10'},
    { name: 'Color', value: 'yellow'},
  ],
  [
    { name: 'Size', value: '10'},
    { name: 'Color', value: 'pink'},
  ],
];
```

My expected output is:

```js
const outputProducts = [
  {
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '10'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'yellow'},
    ],
  },
  {
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '10'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'pink'},
    ],
  },
];
```

Here is my code. Try with a **filter** then **find** and **some** function. But I don't know where is my mistake.

```js
  const filterProducts = products.filter((el) => {
   return el.options.find((o) => {
     return conditions.find((m) => {
       return m.every(({ name, value }) => o.name == name && o.value === value);
     });
   });
 });
```

But did not get the correct result.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try using the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) methods with arrow function syntax like the following way:

```js
const products = [
  {
    options: [
       { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '10'},
       { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'yellow'},
    ],
  },
  {
    options: [
       { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '20'},
       { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'yellow'},
    ],
  },
  {
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '10'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'pink'},
    ],
  },
  { 
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '20'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'pink'}
    ],
  },
  {
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Size', value: '39'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Color', value: 'pink'},
    ],
   },
];

const conditions = [
  [
    { name: 'Size',value: '10'},
    { name: 'Color', value: 'yellow'},
  ],
  [
    { name: 'Size', value: '10'},
    { name: 'Color', value: 'pink'},
  ],
];

const filterProducts = products.filter(product =>
  //iterate over conditions to check if any of the conditions match the options of the current product
  conditions.some(condition =>
    //check if all the key-value pairs in each condition match the options of the current product
    condition.every(({ name, value }) =>
      //returns true if any of the conditions match, and the product is included in the result.
      product.options.some(option => option.name === name && option.value === value)
    )
  )
);

console.log(filterProducts);
```